# Working with dialog box to download file from a site in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, urllib2, mechanize

I am trying to automate testing of a site , which has a form to be filled and download an excel sheet. The data is posted in HTTP request. Since it has that , i used **urllib2** to get the url working but there is a **Open/Save Dialog Box** which pops up to download the sheet.

So I started using **selenium** which can handle this feature , but there is javascript function involved and im unable to pass values to it.

This is the problem im facing withe the datepicker used  *calendarDateInput.js* and a function of it is used like

```
 <td align="center"><script>DateInput('startDate', true, 'YYYY-MM-DD')</script> </td>
```

I need to pass my own date through selenium and tried this :

First i tried with

```
driver.find_element_by_id("endDate_Year_ID").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("endDate_Year_ID").send_keys("2013")
```

Then since it was not working , i resorted to using javascript

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('endDate_Year_ID').value = '2013'")
```

The value is not getting populated and im stuck here

Is there any other way in mechanize or urllib2 to handle dialog box to save the files or any other module where i can handle javascript in python

Im doing this test on a **linux** machine and **send_keys** is not working for any site

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific. Provide the code you are using with the link to the website included. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe : I have updated the code with which im facing the problem

Comment: @alecxe : Im running this on linux , send_keys isnt working .Could there be a problem with that? Or any other firefox settings which is disabling this ?Is there any other function to perform the actions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **bypass the dialog box and automatically download the file**, you can set such a setting in your browser profile.

If using Firefox, you can try the following settings.  Make sure to set your /path/to/downloads and Content-Type ( application/download, application/octet-stream, text/csv, etc.)

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/path/to/downloads/')
fp.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir", '/path/to/downloads/')
fp.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder", '/path/to/downloads/')
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "CONTENT-TYPE")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","CONTENT-TYPE")
```

Then make sure to pass that profile to your instance of the browser:

```
mydriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer but i should be able to fill the form before i start to download it.

Comment: There is a new browser window being opened with these preferences set , am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Yea for some reason, I had two instances of webdriver.Firefox().  It should just be mydriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)